# what does this line means #![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]?

Tags: rust

[image]

```rs
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Those are conditional attributes, a feature of rust. In a nutshell you say if `not(feature = "std")` is true i.e. feature `std` is disabled, then turn on attribute called `no_std` module wide as indicated by the `!` after pound `#`. Enabling `no_std` prevents you from importing the rust std lib and making use of it. This is necessary for pallets as they run inside a wasm interpreter and do not have access to machine resources which is in turn required by rust std lib.

Answer (score 3):

In short, it means: If `"std"` is not enabled, flag/mark this crate/module as `no_std` while compiling.

All you need is this: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html